# What happens to convexity when the covariance matrix is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Suppose I have a quadratic programming problem with objective function of the form:

$x^T \Sigma x\ +\ ...$

The objective function is convex only if $\Sigma$ which is a covariance matrix is semi-definite positive. However under some extreme circumstances $\Sigma$ may become singular / rank deficient and span a set of possible optimization solutions in that case not just one. When $\Sigma$ becomes singular is it still semi-definite positive and the optimization problem convex or not?

Comment: Certainly not all singular matrices are positive semidefinite, but some are.

Comment: I think you're very likely working with wrong definitions of positive definiteness and positive semidefiniteness, and even the concept of invertibility of matrices. Reading this wikipedia page might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Inverse_of_positive_definite_matrix.